# Threading a TCP Controller in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

Today i was testing my project which i have builded in two different controllers, a ViewController and a TCPController. My ViewController instansiates the TCPController (singleton) which updates output and input stream. Now under the test i could determine some lagging on the GUI interface, which was easy to blame the TCPController for.

Is there a best practice on how to thread the TCP controller (client side) before i use the standard tutorial on Apples website: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html

Example on how this would be resolved is very welcome.

Comment: Unless you really want to recreate a TCP manager object, Robbie Hanson has an excellent and widely used one called CocoaAsyncSocket which I highly recommend: https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket. At the very least you should look at it to see how this kind of thing is done. Pay particular attention to the newer GCD implementation.

Comment: I think i will be refactoring my code to this asyncsocket in the summer holidays.. Thanks for the loink..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading documentation is always a good idea.

What you do depends in part on your communication framework.  Most good frameworks already provide asynchronous methods.  If yours does not.  Look for something else.

Barring that, in general, you will want to execute your code in a background thread.  If it is one long job, then the following should do the trick...

```
dispatch_queue_t commQ = dispatch_queue_create("some.unique.labe", 0);
dispatch_async(commQ, ^{
    // Now, any code running in this block is running in a different thread.
    // When you get done, and want to talk to the UI, you must use the main
    // queue for any UIKit calls...

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Now this code is running on the main queue
        // Do all your UI stuff here...

    });
});
dispatch_release(commQ);
```

Comment: I have a button that creates some continous data which are sent directly to the outputStream.. It does not exactly get a chance to send them correctly before i release the button. While button down and moving the input it lags around. So i assume that i need to call my function in a thread if possible? Im using a `action@selector` right now.

Comment: Yes, in the button action, spin off an async task to do that work.  It will return immediately, and when the data is ready (or at various time when pieces of data are ready) just run your UI code in a block running in the main queue.

Comment: I tried inserting the code quickly and populating the `dispatch_async(commQ, ^{` with my code, which actually gave the same result as before. Is there no way that the outputStream can run in its own task permanently?

Comment: When you kick off that function, it will run until you exit the function.  So, *you* determine how long it will run.  You can kick off a bunch of tasks that execute one after the other on the same queue, or you can just run one big task that runs as long as your app is running.

Comment: that sounds actually interesting. I might even avoid using a selector in such case as i could just determine whether a value from my control has changed since last time or not. Whats best practice for placing the code execution?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "Whats best practice for placing the code execution?"

Comment: well after debugging some more i could see that it had not made any difference in my system. My action selector was still trying to call the method that executes the method which sends data through the outputStream, but theres still something making it lag very badly until the button is released. I sense that my TCP controller has to run on a seperate thread to resolve this issue. Although i could use a quick solution right now.

Comment: Whatever you run inside that dispatch_async **will** run in a separate thread... so I guess I just don't understand.  If you want to be sure, just set a breakpoint there, and look at which thread its running in.  It will NOT be the main thread.